# How can I extract or uncompress gzip file using php?

Tags: php, gzip, compression

```
function uncompress($srcName, $dstName) {
    $sfp = gzopen($srcName, "rb");
    $fp = fopen($dstName, "w");

    while ($string = gzread($sfp, 4096)) {
        fwrite($fp, $string, strlen($string));
    }
    gzclose($sfp);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I tried this code but this does not work, I get:

> **Internal Server Error**
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@domain.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error. More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>   *Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

Comment: We need a lot more than "it doesn't work". What does it do? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Your code looks good (it chunks the data in 4kb blocks) so it should be light on RAM. What error(s) is/are you getting?

Comment: I get nothing simply I does not uncompress any of my files

Comment: I want to know how much is buffer size I must use for many files

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try this found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293121/how-can-i-unzip-a-gz-file-with-php)

```
//This input should be from somewhere else, hard-coded in this example
$file_name = '2013-07-16.dump.gz';

// Raising this value may increase performance
$buffer_size = 4096; // read 4kb at a time
$out_file_name = str_replace('.gz', '', $file_name); 

// Open our files (in binary mode)
$file = gzopen($file_name, 'rb');
$out_file = fopen($out_file_name, 'wb'); 

// Keep repeating until the end of the input file
while (!gzeof($file)) {
    // Read buffer-size bytes
    // Both fwrite and gzread and binary-safe
    fwrite($out_file, gzread($file, $buffer_size));
}

// Files are done, close files
fclose($out_file);
gzclose($file);
```

Comment: Great help for me. works fine. and easy to use.

Comment: Good code in, general. But I wouldn't take the str_replace(gz) for granted, as sometimes the input file is a /tmp/<random> because it comes from an upload in $_FILES