# Gzip decompressing

Tags: php, lua, gzip, compression

I'm learning php and for a small project I'm sending raw http posts to my web-server from a lua console. Anyway it's g-zipped and I cannot figure out how to decompress it. When I go to this site http://i-tools.org/gzip and try it, it doesn't work UNLESS I uncheck 'GZIP-compatible encoding'

my php code is

```
    <?php
  $file = 'place.txt';
      $post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
      echo($post_data);
      file_put_contents($file, $post_data . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the empty spaces before the opening tag "<?php" ?

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to decompress GZip in lua or in PHP?

lua:
[lua compress DEFLATE](https://github.com/davidm/lua-compress-deflatelua)

PHP:
[How can I extract or uncompress gzip file using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265914/how-can-i-extract-or-uncompress-gzip-file-using-php)