# I can not unzip a .gz file php

Tags: php, gzip, compression

I tried unzipping a file with extension *.gz*, but I get the following error.

> Warning: gzuncompress(): data error

My code is very simple:

```
<?php
  $filename = "file.gz";
  $uncompressed = gzuncompress($filename);
  echo $uncompressed;
?>
```

How can I solve that?

Thank you.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265914/how-can-i-extract-or-uncompress-gzip-file-using-php

Comment: The parameter for `gzuncompress` is `$data`, not `$filename`!

Comment: Thank you Salim Ibrogimov,this worked.