# PHP: how to download gziped content?

Tags: php

file1.avi was gunziped into file1.gz and uploaded to server.

When someone downloads file1.gz, I want to serve directly file1.avi :

It means: the script decompresses file1.gz and sends its content: file1.avi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract or uncompress gzip file using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265914/how-can-i-extract-or-uncompress-gzip-file-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`gzdecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) :)